# Showing a unit count with a table of data (fact table)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

What is the best practice to display a unit count and a wide fact table on one page. Before I used to show the unit count in a card, turn off visual level filters and show only page level filters but this returns not as accurate results and would like to go back to using visual level fiters,

should I display the unit count in the table or does someone have a better way of doing the above or if anyone has a better idea please share?

For one of my report I need to do a sum of the units as it contains sales and cancellations instead of a plain unit count and the sum of the unit count is really messed up, i wouldn't mind advice on this as well from someone who has experienced in this area?

p.s cannot use slicers as there are over 100 fields to filter

Comment: "but this returns not as accurate results" Can you elaborate on this?
Can you provide some examples and/or sample data?

Comment: I have some reports which get data by doing a union on 3 fact tables and one table may be a sales table one table is a cancellation and another is a sold but cancelled this year I do this to get the correct sum of the unit count. But what this does is when I filter the table there is a number of rows in the filter tab which do not match with the number of rows in the table which again do not match  with whats on the card. As I am using a Card visual I need to do page level filters, but when I tested out the visual level filters the count was closer to the expected value.

Comment: sorry cannot share my data, in general was just looking for some advice from someone who has had a similar experience with the problem I have

Comment: also in the case where the result does match I was wanting to still know what are the alternatives to showing a unit count but not the way I am doing which is to show it in a card visual and use page level filters for the table fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your are using what is referred as *implicit measures* for you unit count calculation. Maybe by selecting an ID field from your fact table and selecting the *count* aggregation.

To answer your question, and if my first assumption is right.

> In general was just looking for some advice from someone who has had a similar experience with the problem I have

My advice, based on the information you've provided is that you should probably write an *explicit* measure for your calculation – e.g. unit count. In general *my* recommandation is that: *there is nothing wrong with implicit measures, you just never use them.*

With very simple DAX, you can have a lot of control on how your measure is calculated and get rid of handling lots of filters at visual level.

Here is a *template* for you measure :

```
UnitCount =
CALCULATE(
    DISINCTCOUNT(Table[ID]),
    Table[Movement] = 'Sale', // This is just an example.
    Table[Quantity] > 0 // Again, another example.
)
```

Hope this helps.

Some reading : [Understanding explicit vs. implicit measure](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-explicit-vs-implicit-measures-in-power-bi-e35b578808ca)

Comment: thanks i have been trying to get some kind of advice on this area for a while now had been trying on Power Bi community but to no avail till today thanks again